# Как реализована сетка в google speadsheets (excel)?

Tags: jquery, css3, javascript

Как и с помощью чего реализовать сетку, как в excel, на веб странице?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как и все прочее, при помощи HTML, CSS и JS.

Можете поковырять JQuery-плагин [handsontable](https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable). Демо [тут](http://handsontable.com/).

Comment: То что нужно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Сама сетка, естественно, на таблицах, в этом плане ничего лучше не придумаешь, а вот сама логика работы скорее всего на JS (сложно сказать на чём именно).

На чём вы хотите её реализовать?
Если на [JSF](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces), то можно покапать в сторону [primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/)

Вот [тут](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-05-2008/jw-05-spreadsheets.html?page=1) есть старенький туториал о том как сделать что-то вроде этого на Dojo + OpenOffice.org.

Comment: Спасибо за primefaces, бегло осмотрел его возможности... вах слов нет :)